# Context not recognisied:Method not applicable for arguments

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-context

I'm  trying to make a timer to play an MP3 file every 1.5 seconds(a beep) in my android application. I have the following code and receive the error "The method create (context,int) in the type MediaPlayer is not applicable for the arguments (Beep.RemindTask,int)" in my run function below:

```
package com.example.timer;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

public class Beep {

 Timer timer;

    public Beep() {

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new RemindTask(),
                   0,        //initial delay
                   1*1500);  //subsequent rate
    }

    class RemindTask extends TimerTask {



        public void run() {

            MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beep); 
            mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mPlayer.start();


        }
    }

    public void main(String args[]) {

        new Beep();

    }
}
```

I don't understand why it isn't applicable, the parameters being the same? I know its probably something to do with the context, which I am not entirely sure of, but from here: [What is 'Context' on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android) I know they are used  when creating new objects or accessing shared common resources. I have tried `getApplicationContext()`,`getContext()` and `getBaseContext()` but still receive errors. I believe that everything needed by the beep object to operate is located in this context. Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: `Beep.RemindTask` isn't a `Context`, is it? It's not clear why you'd expect it to work.

Comment: why do you have a `main`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class is a non-activity class so you can't directly get at a context. When you instantiate an instance of Beep from your activity, pass in the activity's context in the constuctor.

Add a variable to your Beep class to hold a context:

```
private Context context;
```

In the constructor, store it:

```
public Beep(Context context) {
this.context=context;
//the rest of your constructor code...
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.beep);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.beep);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're inside of the class RemindTask which extends TimerTask, when you use `this`, you're referring RemindTask.

Use getActivity() to get the Context of the Activity

> MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.beep);

Answer (score 0):

to use the method  ,you should be in an activity or the compiler  should know the context or should know the activity you are working with.To do that

Option 1: you can pass context from activity to this class.
Option 2:you can use getActivity(). followed by your code